# SlidingMenu inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am trying to include SlidingMenu inside a Fragment. The reason why I wanted to put a SlidingMenu inside a fragment because one of the page of my viewPager will be displaying it. Just confused on how I extend a fragment since one of the examples extends `SlidingFragmentActivity`.

```
 public class Activity A extends SlidingFragmentActivity {}
```

I been trying like this,

```
public class ResponsiveUIActivityE extends SherlockFragment{

    View rootView;
    private Fragment mContent;

       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           SlidingFragmentActivity2 sl = new SlidingFragmentActivity2();



           getActivity().setTitle("R.string.responsive_ui");
           LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           rootView = vi.inflate(R.layout.two_fragments, null, false);

        // check if the content frame contains the menu frame
            if (rootView.findViewById(R.layout.two_fragments) == null) {
                //sl.setBehindContentView(R.layout.two_fragments);
                sl.getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(true);
                sl.getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                // show home as up so we can toggle


            } else {

            }

            // set the Above View Fragment
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                mContent = getChildFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
            if (mContent == null)
                mContent = new BirdGridFragment(0); 
            getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
            .commit();

            // set the Behind View Fragment
            getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new BirdMenuFragment())
            .commit();

            // customize thse SlidingMenu
            SlidingMenu sm = sl.getSlidingMenu();
            sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
            sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
            sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
            sm.setBehindScrollScale(0.25f);
            sm.setFadeDegree(0.25f);
            }

        return rootView;
       }
}
```

**SlidingFragmentActivity2**

```
public class SlidingFragmentActivity2 extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase  {

    private SlidingActivityHelper mHelper;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHelper = new SlidingActivityHelper(this);
        mHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onPostCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHelper.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#findViewById(int)
     */
    @Override
    public View findViewById(int id) {
        View v = super.findViewById(id);
        if (v != null)
            return v;
        return mHelper.findViewById(id);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#setContentView(int)
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int id) {
        setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, null));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#setContentView(android.view.View)
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View v) {
        setContentView(v, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#setContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
     */
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View v, LayoutParams params) {
        super.setContentView(v, params);
        mHelper.registerAboveContentView(v, params);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setBehindContentView(int)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(int id) {
        setBehindContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, null));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setBehindContentView(android.view.View)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(View v) {
        setBehindContentView(v, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setBehindContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)
     */
    public void setBehindContentView(View v, LayoutParams params) {
        mHelper.setBehindContentView(v, params);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#getSlidingMenu()
     */
    public SlidingMenu getSlidingMenu() {
        return mHelper.getSlidingMenu();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        mHelper.toggle();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#showAbove()
     */
    public void showContent() {
        mHelper.showContent();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#showBehind()
     */
    public void showMenu() {
        mHelper.showMenu();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#showSecondaryMenu()
     */
    public void showSecondaryMenu() {
        mHelper.showSecondaryMenu();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingActivityBase#setSlidingActionBarEnabled(boolean)
     */
    public void setSlidingActionBarEnabled(boolean b) {
        mHelper.setSlidingActionBarEnabled(b);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onKeyUp(int, android.view.KeyEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean b = mHelper.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        if (b) return b;
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Logcat:

```
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity2.getSlidingMenu(SlidingFragmentActivity2.java:101)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.actionbarsherlock.sample.styled.ResponsiveUIActivityE.onCreateView(ResponsiveUIActivityE.java:41)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1038)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15181)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-07 15:23:13.943: E/AndroidRuntime(10612):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 15:28:13.978: I/Process(10612): Sending signal. PID: 10612 SIG: 9
```

Comment: why do you want the slidingMenu to be inside a slidingMenu? if you want to recycle the views inside it in a pager why don't you make the view as a fragment to be placed in the sliding menu or in the page? and by the way from the last support library release you can use the standard DrawerLayout. Since you are implementing it right now i strongly suggest you to go standard :).

Comment: The reason why i choose slidingMenu library because, I have an existing example. I am not sure how to do DrawerLayout. Can I put a DrawerLayout inside one of my fragment page? thanks

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't. in the end it can be abstract to a ViewGroup so i guess it will work without problems. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html. here is the documnetation of the DrawerLayout.

Comment: and here is the Official tutorial.
It's pretty straight forward: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Appreciate that! I am now studying the DrawerLayout, and been trying to do the `onSwipe(int direction){` so that if I swipe it from left to right the drawerLayout with be hidden or shown. Please Give your answer to this, and I accept it thee. If you want you may include the `onSwipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last support library release you can use the standard [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html).
Since you are implementing it right now i strongly suggest you to go standard instead of using external libraries.

I don't see any reason why it should't work inside a ViewPager.

here is the [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).